# SwiftUI and Combine, how to create a reusable publisher to check if a string is empty

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to learn SwiftUI and Combine syntax and am trying to understand how to create a reusable publisher that will check if a String is empty.

I've got a SwiftUI with 5 TextFields which using @Binding to connect them to my data model object.

```
class DataWhatIsLoanPayment: ObservableObject {
    // Input
    @Published var pv = ""
    @Published var iyr = ""
    // a bunch more fields...

    // Output
    @Published var isvalidform = false
}
```

I want to enable the Calculate button once all of the fields are filled in (isEmpty == false).

I'm following along with https://peterfriese.dev/swift-combine-love/, and I was able to get my SwiftUI to properly enable/disable my Calculate button by creating an `isValidPVPublisher` and an `isValidIYRPublisher` and combing them in an `isValidFormPublisher`, like so:

```
private var isValidPVPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    $pv
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { input in
            return input.isEmpty == false
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

private var isValidIYRPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    $iyr
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { input in
            return input.isEmpty == false
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


private var isValidFormPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    Publishers.CombineLatest(isValidPVPublisher, isValidIYRPublisher)
        .map { pvIsValid, iyrIsValid in
            return pvIsValid && iyrIsValid
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

init() {        
    isValidFormPublisher
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .assign(to: \.isValidForm, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)
}
```

However, I'm going to have a lot more than 2 fields, and I'm going to have a lot of other forms in my app in which I will want to check if my fields are empty. And repeating `.debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main).removeDuplicates().map { input in return input.isEmpty == false }.eraseToAnyPublisher()` over and over again is a bad idea.

I want to create a reusable `NotEmptyPublisher`, or something like that, which takes a field binding, like my `$pv` and sets up the chain as show in the `isValidPVPublisher` above. So I can have something like:

```
// Something like this, but I'm not sure of the syntax...
private var isValidPVPublisher = NotEmptyPublisher(field:$pv)
// instead of ...
private var isValidPVPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    $pv
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { input in
            return input.isEmpty == false
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I'm having a trouble parsing a lot of Swift syntax that I'm not familiar with and I can't seem to figure out how to do it, and every example I find on the web is just defining the publisher chain inline instead of in a reusable fashion.

How can I create a reusable publisher so that I don't have to repeat these inline publishers which all do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are!

```
extension Publisher where Output == String {
    func isStringInhabited() -> Publishers.Map<Self, Bool> {
        map { !$0.isEmpty }
    }
}
```

`$0` is shorthand for the first argument to the closure, `$1` means the second, and so on and so forth.

`!` is the `Bool` inversion operator, prefixing `!` is shorthand for suffixing `== false`.

Now, as to your question about reuse, you don't need to overkill things that hard, you can just create a function.

```
private func isValidTransform<P: Publisher>(input: P) -> some Publisher where P.Output == String {
    input
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .isStringInhabited()
}
```

`P` is a generic, which means it could be any type whatsoever as long as that type conforms to `Publisher`. The `where` clause allows us to constrain this conformance further, denoting that we can only operate on `Publisher`s when their `Output` is `String`. `some Publisher` gives us an opaque return type to save us from having to write the type signature of a `Publisher` that has been transformed multiple times, you can change this to `AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>` and use `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` if you like but I recommend only using that erasure at the time of need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the explanation of the syntax involved. It's greatly appreciated!